# how to embed a twitter post in flutter web

Tags: html, flutter, iframe, twitter

I tried this:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
        'iframeElement',
        (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
          ..width = '640'
          ..height = '360'
          ..src =
              '<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="he" data-dnt="true" data-theme="dark"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Sunsets don&#39;t get much better than this one over <a href="https://twitter.com/GrandTetonNPS?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">@GrandTetonNPS</a>. <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/nature?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#nature</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/sunset?src=hash&amp;ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">#sunset</a> <a href="http://t_dot_co/YuKy2rcjyU">pic.twitter.com/YuKy2rcjyU</a></p>&mdash; US Department of the Interior (@Interior) <a href="https://twitter.com/Interior/status/463440424141459456?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">5 במאי 2014</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>'
          ..style.border = 'none');
    super.initState();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'iframeElement')),
    );
  }
```

but it's not working.